# How to format number without trailing fractional 0?

Tags: sql, postgresql, types, formatting, rounding

Values of column `A` in Table `T`:

```
9.2135
13.0000
```

If I use function `round(A,3)`, the result is:

```
9.214 
13.000
```

How to get this:

```
9.214
13
```

Comment: This isn't about rounding.  This is about converting integers to text.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Simply casting the column as a float achieves this

```
select round(9.2135,3)::float;
```

returns 9.214

```
select round(13.00000,3)::float;
```

returns 13

Comment: Do not use this. I added an answer.

Answer (score 2):

**Don't** cast to `float`. Floating point numbers only store approximations if the number cannot be represented exactly. You may get unexpected results. Example:

```
SELECT 0.2::float
```

Result:

```
0.20000000000000001
```

- [What Every Programmer Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://floating-point-gui.de/)

For representation purposes (displaying a number as text) use [**`to_char()`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-formatting.html).
It's a bit tricky to display the decimal point only with significant fractional digits. Adding [`rtrim()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) for that:

```
SELECT rtrim(to_char(nr, 'FM99999999990.999'), '.') AS nr
```

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d41d8/3871)

Comment: I use SELECT 0.2::float ; result =0.2 in Postgresql

Comment: @DT: this may be your client software interfering and cannot be relied upon. I updated the fiddle to clarify: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d41d8/3871